# Independent random generator in C

Tags: c, random

I know that in C we can use rand() to generate random numbers and use srand() to set seed.
However I now want an independent random generator (like a variable, or define a class).

---

By independent random number generator I mean: in the program there are multiple parts using randomness. If I use srand() to modify the seed in one part, randomness at other parts would be affected. That's why I want an independent struct to control the randomness.
I saw this:

```
unsigned long next=1;
int rand(void) /* NOT RECOMMENDED (see text) */
{
    next = next*1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next=seed;
}
```

Are there better ways?

Comment: What do you mean by `independent random generator`? Please elaborate.

Comment: Didn't your research turn up anything useful on this much-debated topic?

Comment: If you want actual random numbers, you are going to need expensive hardware.

Comment: there are no classes in `C` ...

Comment: [This problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=165) describes the "Blum Blum Shub" pseudo-random number generator. Where `s(0) = 290797` and then `s(n+1) = (s(n) * s(n)) modulo 50515093`.

Comment: C does not support classes.

Comment: Check out something like my ojrandlib.

Comment: If you want to stick to standard libraries and don't need high quality pseduo random numbers, you might want to look at rand_r.  Note that per the man page:  The value pointed to by the seedp argument of rand_r() provides only a very small amount of state, so this function will be a weak pseudo-random generator.  Try drand48_r(3) instead (but I'm not sure if drand48_r is portable or unique to Linux etc.), and if you want portable, there are libraries you probably want

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are describing is sometimes called *random-streams* or *random-synchronization*.

While you easily could build something on your own, i recommend the [Gnu Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generator-Examples.html#Random-Number-Generator-Examples), which has many different high-quality PRNGs and also a good abstract interface which is easy to use in this *random-stream*-setting.

The above link gives you an example where a RNG object is created for further use. In your case, you would build multiple random-streams and use these in your different parts of the code. Each random-stream is therefore only modified (internal-state) if exactly this random-stream was called (and independent on the usages of the others).